# Problema al mostrar un numero float en java

Tags: java, float

tengo un problema al mostrar un numero de tipo float, por ejemplo, si es 10000000000 me muestra 1E10. Como podria hacer para que me lo muestre tal cual lo pongo y no de forma exponencial?

Se agradece mucho su respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Cómo estás intentando mostrarlo. Una pregunta sin código es como un jardín sin flores :)

Answer (score 5):

Te recomiendo usar uno de los formateadores que vienen en la librería estándar de Java: `NumberFormat` o [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) (que extiende al primero):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es"));
String sNum = nf.format(num); //puede ser un long, double...
```

Así además puedes controlar el uso de comas o puntos como separador de decimales o millares.

Answer (score 4):

Para números tan grandes si no quieres perder precisión puedes usar `java.math.BigDecimal`:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Prueba {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("10000000000");
        num = num.add(new BigDecimal("1.7"));
        System.out.println(num); // 10000000001.7
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas sencilla para mostrar el número tal como es, sin ninguna notación, es usar el método toString :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Prueba {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("10000000000");
        System.out.println(num.toString()); // 10000000000
    }
}
```

La salida del programa :

```
aoz001es :JAVA $ java Prueba 
10000000000
```